# How to define multiple Locable Resource labels in Jenkins JCasC plugin's .yaml config?

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-plugins

I got a problem defining a list of `Lockable Resources` using `configuration-as-code (JCasC)` Jenkins plugin. There is an official example, which works fine:

```
unclassified:
  lockableResourcesManager:
    declaredResources:
      - name: "Resource_A"
        description: "Description_A"
        labels: "Label_A"
        reservedBy: "Reserved_A"
```

But when i want to define more than one label, and trying this:

```
unclassified:
  lockableResourcesManager:
    declaredResources:
      - name: "Resource_A"
        description: "Description_A"
        labels: 
          - "Label_A"
          - "Label_B"
        reservedBy: "Reserved_A"
```

I get an exception:

```
    io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: Item isn't a Scalar
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.model.CNode.asScalar(CNode.java:26)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.PrimitiveConfigurator.configure(PrimitiveConfigurator.java:45)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:353)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:276)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.DataBoundConfigurator.check(DataBoundConfigurator.java:101)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:344)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:287)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:352)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:287)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$7(ConfigurationAsCode.java:746)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:696)
Caused: io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: unclassified: error configuring 'unclassified' with class io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.GlobalConfigurationCategoryConfigurator configurator
```

How can i define multiple labels properly?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out. Everything you need is split labels with space:

```
    unclassified:
  lockableResourcesManager:
    declaredResources:
      - name: "Resource_A"
        description: "Description_A"
        labels: 
          - "Label_A Label_B"
        reservedBy: "Reserved_A"
```